# Detect CTRL+A in a texbox

Tags: winapi, textbox, keyboard-events

I have a main window `hwndMain` and a multiline `Edit` textbox:

```
hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(0, L"EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 0, 0, 300, 200, hwndMain, 0, (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hwndMain, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
```

I use this to detect <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in the textbox (because strangely, it's not available out-of-the-box):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if (wParam == VK_CONTROL)  // something here missing for detecting "A"
            {
                SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);    // select all ; this code works on its own, tested
            }
            ...
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ anything.

**What is wrong?**

*Note: Ok the code for detecting A is still missing (i still don't know how to do it), but the code here should work for any <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+key...*

Comment: A standard Edit control will handle Ctrl+A already. Don't break it and you won't have to reimplement it.

Comment: The WM_KEYDOWN message is sent to the edit control, not your window.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [About Keyboard Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267.aspx), in case you want to override the default implementation (selecting the entire content, in some locales anyway).

Comment: @IInspectable I don't want to **override** CTRL+A, I want to *allow* 'select all' with CTRL+A, because, I don't know why, but CTRL+A doesn't work by default in my Edit...  (it works in all other software).  Does CTRL+A work by default on https://github.com/josephernest/NeverForget/blob/master/src/neverforget.cpp for you ?

Comment: When you have some message processing like for accelerators and this accelerator also consume Ctrl+A your edit control will not receive any key for that.

Comment: @HansPassant Should I have two functions `LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` then? One for the main window, and a second one for the edit window? Isn't there a way to do it with only one ?

Comment: @Basj: You seem to have skipped over the *Mandatory reading* part. Here is a vital piece of information from the document: *"The **window that has the keyboard focus** receives all keyboard messages until the focus changes to a different window."*

Comment: If you want to see messages that are sent to the edit control then you have to subclass it.  Contrary to popular opinion, a multi-line edit control does *not* implement Ctrl+A.  You have to implement it yourself.  An accelerator is the normal approach for a Notepad style app.

Comment: Oh ok @HansPassant, so you say it's normal that CTRL+A does not work already? This is interesting, because I searched for hours where could be the bug making that CTRL+A=>select all doesn't work directly.  Ok. if you have a few hints on how to solve this 'select ALL' story on https://github.com/josephernest/NeverForget/blob/master/src/neverforget.cpp#L35, I would be interested for a pastebin!

Comment: A *Multiline* Edit control is not a *standard* Edit control. It's probably a good idea to both provide the code that creates the control in your question, as well as specifically note that you are using a `ES_MULTILINE` Edit control in the title/text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for WM_KEYDOWN for A and than use GetKeyState

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
  {
    if (wParam=='A' && (::GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000)!=0)
    {
      SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);    // select all
    }
```

Remember that WM_KEYDOWN is only sent to the window that has the focus and not to parent windows.

Comment: It does not work. By the way, I even tried `case WM_KEYWDOWN: { MessageBox(...); }` but nothing happens : it seems that `WM_KEYDOWN` is not triggered *for the main window* at all when I write in an `Edit` textbox... Why?

Comment: @Basj: *"Remember that WM_KEYDOWN is only sent to the window that has the focus and not to parent windows."*

Comment: Should I have two functions LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) then? One for the main window, and a second one for the edit window? Isn't there a way to do it with only one @IInspectable ?

Comment: @Basj: Yes, [Subclassing Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) requires a window procedure for your subclassed control. I would, however, suggest that you actually fix the bug, instead of working around it. You broke standard functionality, now fix it.

Answer (score 1):

After you create all your windows:

```
hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(.....)
...

//Subbclassing
SetWindowSubclass(hwndEdit, (SUBCLASSPROC)EditWndProc, 0, 1);


LRESULT CALLBACK EditWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwrefData){

    switch(message){ //handle the messages   
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            //your code

           break;
        default:   //for messages that we don't deal with
            return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: @xMRi and γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε : The conjunction of **both** your answers solves the problem. Which one should I accept? Dilemma!

Comment: @Basj Your question is answered by xMRi, so he should get it. I just helped you with *Subclassing*.